# Why is Cloud Run serving responses from wrong region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run instance running Django, both the GCP console and gcloud confirm **the instance is deployed to `europe-west1` region**.

However, using a tool like https://www.site24x7.com/find-website-location.html ** Django seems to be serving responses from Mountain View, USA.**

This is not a transient issue, its come to light as I run a number of scrapers on this instance and on international sites they are receiving responses that are targeted to the US.

Comment: It might be that the IP address is an Anycast IP ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast

What that would mean is that when you try and reach the server (europe-west1) the IP address resolves to the closest IP address.  Where in the world are you originating your requests to the server?   I'm assuming that if we actually hit the server, its logs would show it to be running in europe.

Comment: no, I dont think so, I run some scrapers on the cloud run instance (as well as a website) so they are acting as clients rather than servers, they make requests to ebay for example, and the content they are receiving shows ebay believes the request has originated from the US. I have used a third-party proxy with geo-targetting to prove to myself thats whats happening but its not a long-term solution, hence I want to know why I'm getting this behavior on Cloud Run.

Comment: I am in the UK fyi.

Comment: Ohh ... let me play back what I think I just heard.  You have Cloud Run servers deployed to Europe.  These make outgoing REST/HTTP requests.  The recipients sees the requests appear to arrive from IP addresses located in the US.  Can you clarify what you think the recipients of the requests are seeing as source addresses?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times, a few by me. You cannot reliably detect the location of an IP address. These sites use the "registered address", this does not mean the physical address. For Google, their IP addresses can be moved at will (software defined networking). For Anycast addresses, they are at all points globally where they are assigned at the same time. You can get a rough indication of how far an IP address is from you via trace routing. That is not reliable either. I used your link to test one of my servers in Seattle. Your link thinks my servers are in Dallas, TX.

Answer (score 2):

@Kolban's analysis is correct.

All Google Cloud IPs (including the Compute Engine VMs) will seem like they're coming out of "Mountain View, CA, USA" regardless of the region they're running in. This is because they belong to the same global IP block that Google has.

This IP pool is also likely used by other Google products like Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine and Compute Engine as well.

Most probably, Google doesn’t dedicate certain IP ranges to specific regions, as Google’s IP blocks are meant to be routed to the nearest Google datacenter, then enter Google’s private network, and be routed internally.

My recommendation would be to not to use the IP address of a Cloud Run service (or a Compute Engine VM) to determine its region. This information is available inside the VM or container on the "metadata service".

Answer (score 0):

On your location web site, simply enter the domain name `run.app`. You will find the same thing, Montain View, CA. In fact, when you register a domain, you put a location of this domain. Your website use this metadata to answer you a static answer.

However, to be sure, I ran a test

I deployed 2 services
[image]

And I ran a test on both

```
> curl https://europe-west1-hello-<hash>-ew.a.run.app -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}\n"
0.081340

> curl https://us-central1-hello-<hash>-uc.a.run.app -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_starttransfer}\n"
0.175606
```

I'm located in France. Europe West 1 (Belgium) only 81ms. US central 1 (8000km from me) 175ms.

That's consistent!